# Cannot Reindex from a duplicate axis while subsetting

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, subset, valueerror

I have the following dataframe:

```
print(df)

 Col    Col     Col  Name
  A      B       C   Alex
  B      B       C   Jack
  B      A       A   Mark
```

I would like to get the following result, where **at least one A** appears:

```
 Col    Col     Col  Name
  A      B       C   Alex
  B      A       A   Mark
```

I tried:

final_df = df["Col"] == "A" but it gives me "*ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem you have duplicated columns names, so if select `df["Col"]` get all columns called `Col`.

Possible solution is compare all columns with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for check at least one `True` per row:

```
df = df[(df == 'A').any(1)]
print (df)
  Col Col Col
0   A   B   C
2   B   A   A
```

Details:

```
print ((df == 'A'))
     Col    Col    Col
0   True  False  False
1  False  False  False
2  False   True   True

print ((df == 'A').any(1))
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```